# Select css from header

Tags: jquery, css

How can I get `URL` property value from element defined as

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">.sprite-thumb {background-image:url(example.jpg);}</style>
   </head>
</html>
```

I tried `$(data).find("header").css("sprite-thumb")` but got `undefined`

Comment: What is the element `data`? Are you getting the html back from an ajax call? `header` won't be found as you don't have a `header` element. You cannot read css properties like that. `.css` is used to get/set css properties off an element not read the defined properties in your stylesheets. You could grab all elements of class `sprite-thumb` off your html and read the background-image property with `$('.sprite-thumb').css("background-image")` but I think you need to define what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: example of data  element is quoted before. in <html>...</html>

Comment: You don't have a `data` element in the example above... so `$(data)` should give you `ReferenceError: data is not defined` or something similar depending on browser...

Comment: I have a variable called `data` in my code, which contains elements quoted in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var target = $('.sprite-thumb').css('background-image'),
    bg = target.replace(/(^(url\()|\)$)/g,"");
```

It basically uses [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) jQuery function to retrieve the value for `background-image` and then remove `url(` and `)` from it, leaving just the url.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P5qge/5/)

Comment: this regular expression will remove every occurrence of `{`,`u`,`r`,`l`,`(`,`)` and `}` characters.

Comment: also, at least one element with specified class needs to exist in DOM, otherwise too this won't work.